# How do i make a function that drops connect 4 checkers on specific column based on user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to make a connect 4 game but the given dimensions of the board are decided via user input, I have a basic idea on what to do but Im still struggling alot. The gameplay should happen under the drop_disc(c) function!

code:

```
# %load connect_n.py

WHITE_DISK = '\u26AA'
BLACK_DISK = '\u26AB'
FW_SPACE = '\u3000' # fullwidth space
FW_LINE = '\u2015' # fullwidth horizontal line

# the game itself
game = { 
    'N' : 4,    
    'board':[], # the connect-n board
    'moves':[] # the moves by players    
}

def create_board(n):
    '''create the board for the Connect-N game'''
    game['N'] = n
    
    # your code should instead create an empty board with N+3 rows and N+2 Columns
    # example code below, creating a board with 4 rows and 3 columns, with some pre-filled disks
    # 0 - empty, 1 - white disk, 2 - black disk
    #board = [[0,1,2],[0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0]]
    
    board = []
    for i in range(n+3):
        row = [0]*(n+2)
        board.append(row)
    game['board'] = board
    
def display_board():
    '''print the board content'''
    
    # Unicode example below. You should update the code below by
    # 1. use a for loop
    # 2. allow it to display board of different sizes
    
    w = f'{WHITE_DISK:^3}' # white
    b = f'{BLACK_DISK:^3}' # black
    e = f'{FW_SPACE:^3}' # empty
    separator = FW_LINE*20
    board = game['board']
    for row in range(game['N']+3):
        s = ''
        for col in range(game['N']+2): # you should use nested for loop here
            cell = board[row][col] 
            if cell == 0: 
                s = s + f'| {e}'
            elif cell == 1:
                s = s + f'| {w}'
            elif cell == 2:
                s = s + f'| {b}'
        print(s)
    
def drop_disk(c):
    c = int(input("Whats your move? "))
    for i in range(board[1][C]):
        if c == 0:
            board[i][c] = 2
        break 
    '''drop disk at column c'''
    print('drop disk at...')
    
def save_board(fname):
    file = open(Connect_N, 'w')
    file.write(str(game))
    file.close()
    print("game saved successfully")
    
def load_board(fname):
    file = open(Connect_N, 'r')
    game = ast.literal_eval(file.readline())
    file.close()

N = int (input("please enter board size: ")) # your code should allow user inputs instead
create_board(N)
#game["board"][0][0] = 1
#game["board"][0][1] = 1
#game["board"][1][0] = 2
#print(game["board"])

display_board()
drop_disk(c)
```

it returns the following error when i try to enter a column location:

```
please enter board size: 5
|  　 |  　 |  　 |  　 |  　 |  　 |  　 
|  　 |  　 |  　 |  　 |  　 |  　 |  　 
|  　 |  　 |  　 |  　 |  　 |  　 |  　 
|  　 |  　 |  　 |  　 |  　 |  　 |  　 
|  　 |  　 |  　 |  　 |  　 |  　 |  　 
|  　 |  　 |  　 |  　 |  　 |  　 |  　 
|  　 |  　 |  　 |  　 |  　 |  　 |  　 
|  　 |  　 |  　 |  　 |  　 |  　 |  　 
Whats your move? 2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-c9f13aaeed3f> in <module>
     92 
     93 display_board()
---> 94 drop_disk(c)
     95 
     96 #drop_disk(2) # white drop disk at column 2

<ipython-input-24-c9f13aaeed3f> in drop_disk(c)
     54 def drop_disk(c):
     55     c = int(input("Whats your move? "))
---> 56     for i in range(board[1][C]):
     57         if c == 0:
     58             board[i][c] = 2

NameError: name 'board' is not defined
```

cheers to anyone who can help!

Comment: `board` is a local variable in your function, statement `global board` required in your function where define it.

Comment: No need for global...
Just use board = game['board']

Comment: ok aside from that, is there anything wrong with my drop_disk(c) function? cause i dont understand whats wrong with it. (a bit new to python :/)

Comment: How do you want it to work?
Should also specify the color you want to drop or not?